# Unable to locate an element implemented as Span with Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

When recorded in Selenium IDE, the result is this:

> click
>   //span[@id='some_text']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/hd/font/span/acronym

Here is my entry in Eclipse using WebDriver(Java)

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='some_text']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/h2/font/span/acronym")).click();

Here is the error I receive:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='some_text']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/h2/font/span/acronym"},

HTML

```
<span onclick="change_site"('SITES');" style="cursor:pointer; color:#12345; text-decoration:underline;">
    <acronym title=Site ID:">DEFAULTSITE</acronym>
</span>
```

Comment: <b> This is how the HTML code looks when I inspect the element with FireBug:   "<span onclick="change_site"('SITES');" style="cursor:pointer; color:#12345; text-decoration:underline;"><acronym title=Site ID:">DEFAULTSITE</acronym></span>" I want to click on the "DEFAULTSITE" link

Comment: Thanks for all your responses below. They all seem logical and I don't see why they won't work, but I keep getting the same error. I have tried all the suggestions below. Please let me know if there is any other information that may be helpful.  Is there anything I can provide or do from the Selenium IDE that may be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: Okay I figured it out. I basically had to switch to the appropriate frame first . I used this statement:  driver.swithTo().frame("frame name"), then I clicked on a link using the By.cssSelector. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML provided you can directly access the acronym element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/acronym[@title='Site Id:']")).click();
```

Comment: This Xpath selection results into `InvalidSelectorException`. Can't we try with `By.cssSelector("acronym[title=Site]")).click()`? It's clicking on URL.

Comment: @Mitaleek, by all means you can use cssSelector also. At end of day, its "whatever works" :) .  For xpath not working, providing more html may help, as my answer only limited to given html in the question.

Comment: @Mitaleek, my bad, my xpath in code is using wrong slash. backward instead of forward slashes. edited the answer. you can try xpath too if you want.

Comment: Yeah I also thought that xpath's slash is wrong, it still gives same error, hence thought of making above comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below xPath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//acronym[contains(text(),'DEFAULTSITE')]").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below `xpath`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//acronym[text()='DEFAULTSITE']");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/acronym[text()='DEFAULTSITE']");
```

Or this `css`

```
driver.findElement(By.css("acronym[title='Site']");
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above Xpath has worked for you ,please try the following Xpath

```
//span[@id='some_text']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/hd/font/span/*[name()=acronym]
```

Please let me know if this has helped you or not.